# Is there any practical situation where the response variable of a poisson regression is fuzzy

Tags: regression, logistic, count-data, poisson-regression, fuzzy

In certain models like a logistic model; fuzzy responses can occur. We may have suspicion in determining the state of the response variable (0 or 1) and
therefore, cannot categorize the individual samples in one of two response categories. for example....Hypothetical example..... Suppose I collect data on whether an individual has

1.Malaria 
2.Tuberculosis
3.Anemia

Then my dependent variable is whether that individual has some disease x (0 or 1) which can not be medically directly determined. I would use possibility here and say that may be in the presence of 2 of the above diseases then disease x is highly possible but the fuzziness occurs because there may be a situation where there is only one disease and disease x also exist.

Would I also get such a situation if I have count data as my response variable (Poisson regression).

Comment: Poisson regression is used for count data as dependend variable. Your example with 3 different diseases has a categorial dependend variable, not count data. Therefore Poisson regression is not suitable for your job at hand.

Comment: The above example is for a logistic case! i am looking for such an alternative for a poisson case. I just gave it as an example. All I need is a situation where the outcome of a poisson regression is not precise

Answer (score 0):

The simple approach for such data that would be available out-of-the-box for any model, would be to randomly choose one of the values and fit your standard model. If you repeat this many times, you'd obtain the distributions of possible parameter values and predictions. Your "true" model would lye somewhere within the distribution of the "random" models. Using this together with regular bootstrap would enable you to get the confidence intervals.